# How to make systemd kill or stop respawning the rsyslog daemon

Tags: systemd, rsyslog

It is great that systemd can keep rsyslog daemon alive even when it dies.

But I am crafting a new rsyslog configuration file and need to start this rsyslog daemon in debug mode.  Before I debug `rsyslogd`, I need to stop the production rsyslog daemon, so I executed:

```
systemctl stop rsyslogd.service
```

But that command doesn't stop rsyslog daemon.   Killing it via Unix signal doesn't keep systemd from respawning rsyslogd:

```
kill -KILL <rsyslogd-pid>
```

Even executing `systemctl mask rsyslogd.service` doesn't stop the respawning.

How do I make systemd STOP respawning 'rsyslog' daemon so I can troubleshoot it using debug?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, after reading this bug report link: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815862

This appears counter-intuitive...but the actual steps to perform is you have to stop TWO systemd units, and not just the `rsyslog.service`:

```
systemctl stop syslog.socket rsyslog.service
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `syslog.socket` is not a service, is a socket file, Basically it allow systemd to start rsyslog on demand, only when a connection comes.

Comment: yeap  you are right, the generic term is unit, but a unit can be also a lot more: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html